# Authentication using Rest API Correct Behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, authentication, server-side

I am building a `REST API` and I am in a `login` dilemma. What should happen on a subsequent `login` request once I have already `loggedIn` and before I `SignOut`.

So to simplify I do this:

1. 1st `Login` Request - Response has a `auth_token`
2. 2nd `Login` Request before logging out - what should be the response?

Should it be the same `auth_token` or a new `auth_token` should be generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST should be stateless, there is no "login", or "logout", at least not one that the server tracks. Therefore, nothing should actually happen, the user/client should *always* authenticate, on each request.

This of course does not mean, that you can not cache credentials, but the communication should be stateless nonetheless.

If you are doing HTTP-based authentication, you do not have to worry about this actually, client will always sent authentication information automatically.

Comment: Ya I get all of what you said, I am following the same thing but what should happen on the 2nd login? Should I generate a new auth_token or not?

Comment: Well, if the token is cryptographic, then it does not really matter. If it identifies a server session, then the question is whether you want to give a user a new session or not. That is application specific, there is not best-practice either way. From security perspective it may be better to give out a new token and invalidate the old one.